# git - dealing with divergence from origin/master

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

On a particular project I am using `git` to work on a fork of a shared repo. On this fork only I (and occasionally a bot like [requires.io](https://requires.io/)) have pushed commits to `origin/master`, so there is on concern about overwriting the work of another team member.

Recently, I pushed quite a few commits to a public `origin/master` of my fork and later, I realised some of those commits were not sensible, and wanted to edit or revert them. So, I took a copy of the latest version of the code on disk, reverted about 30 commits and pushed the reverted head to `origin/master`.

Then I rebased the local copy of the repo (which was now about 30 commits ahead of `origin/master`). Now `git` says that my local `HEAD` has diverged from `origin/master` and have 30 and 18 different commits each.

I have two questions about this. Obviously, I want my local commits to be pushed to `origin/master`, I don't want to `pull --rebase` and allow my local commits to be overwritten by the remote commits. Is there a simple way to do this without opening a merge tool frequently?

Secondly, this seems very messy. What workflow should I be using to avoid this sort of situation? Pushing less frequently is not likely to be a useful option here, since the buggy commits I was trying to fix were to do with a `travis.ci` YAML file, which I can only usefully test by pushing to `origin/master`.

Comment: I don't understand the need to move HEAD backwards here.  It's also not clear to me in your question at which points are you dealing with the local repo and when you're dealing with `origin`.  You say "on disk" but don't know what you're referring to there.

Comment: "rebased" - rebased on what?  Squashing/deleting/editing commits *rewrites history*, and if you've already published that history, then you have a sad time (your only solution at that point is to `push --force`, which will annoy the rest of your team).

Comment: Joe - you are probably right that moving HEAD backwards wasn't necessary. I should have read more of the documentation on rebase before I started :( I'll try to edit the question for clarity, but basically everything was on a local copy except for the revert at the top of the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never, ever, rebase remote when there are other people pushing or pulling from it. Otherwise, you're going to upset and frustrate a lot of people.

To do this, just don't push your commits until you're happy with them.

For reverting commits that have been pushed already, use the `git revert` tool to create a revert commit then push that.

This is generally the way my workflow works.

Comment: How do you deal with testing services which work via github web hooks and similar then?

Comment: @snim2: Why does this affect web hooks?

Comment: e.g. you have a service such as CI which requires some configuration. You want to test that config, which can only be done by triggering the service web hook when you push. So, you need to push a commit to test the service, but in doing so you may be pushing a commit you are not entirely happy with (yet).

Comment: @snim2: In that case, I would suggest pushing dummy commits (i.e. commits that don't affect anything, like adding a whitespace to a file, or something).

Comment: And then what? Rebasing them? Presumably you don't actually want that commit in your permanent history?

Comment: @snim2: There is no real solution.  Rewriting published history screws anyone else on your team; you cannot get round that ;(

Comment: @snim2: Well, in that case, `push --force` away!